# How to use a proxy in Cloudflare Worker with javascript fetch-api just like cURL?

Tags: javascript, curl, fetch-api, http-proxy, cloudflare-workers

I am trying to use a proxy in Cloudflare Worker through a GET request to the proxy server. The request works in cURL but not in Worker.

For the last couple of days I have been trying to build a web service in Cloudflare Workers. I need to make a GET request through a proxy. After some research, I learned that Worker's fetch function does not support using proxies and it does not allow me to download needed npm packages for using a proxy.

After learning that, I decided to try another approach: Making GET requests to the proxy server with my desired host.

So I came up with a working cURL command:
`curl -verbose <proxy_url:proxy_port> -H "Proxy-Authorization: Basic <token_here>" -H "host: ipinfo.io"`
And it worked! I get the IP address of my proxy as a response from ipinfo.io.

Then I wrote this code, which basically sends the same request as the cURL command.

```
export default {
    async fetch(request, env, ctx) {
        return await fetch("<proxy_url>:<proxy_port>", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Host": "ipinfo.io",
                "Proxy-Authorization": "Basic <token_here>",
            },
        });
    },
};
```

And when I ran the worker on my local network, I got this result:

> access to <proxy_url:proxy_port> is restricted by firewall. If you think it's mistake, please contact with support via chat.; request_uuid: <token_here>

I said whatever and deployed the worker and this time when I try to connect to the worker, it just said "This page is not working" with the HTTP code of 521.

I also tried to send the same request using Chrome Restman extension and it also returned the same firewall error as the worker.

So this request is only working in cURL and I have no idea why.

As a last effort, I checked the request headers of cURL command with -verbose option. And set them accordingly in the worker.

```
export default {
    async fetch(request, env, ctx) {
        return await fetch("<proxy_url>:<proxy_port>", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Host": "ipinfo.io",
                "User-Agent": "curl/7.81.0",
                "Accept": "*/*",
                "Referer": "rbose",
                "Proxy-Authorization": "<token_here>",
            },
        });
    },
};
```

The results remained the same.

Is it possible to recreate this cURL request in workers? Or is there another solution for using a proxy in Worker?

Thanks in advance.